# MySQL : is it possible to keep a unique index while not locking table except when the value collides?

Tags: mysql, indexing, locking, unique

I have the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE `FooBar` (
  `id` int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foobar_id` int(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `foobar_id` (`foobar_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Based on my testing, whenever `foobar_id` is updated, any other update involving `foobar_id` will be locked until the first one ends.

What I want ideally is when someone is updating a not colliding value the table won't be locked

```
begin;

update `FooBar` set foobar_id=2 where id=1;

commit;
```

```
begin;

update `FooBar` set foobar_id=3 where id=2;

commit;
```

These two queries obviously will not collide with each other and the second one ideally should go through before the first one commit if the first update is not setting it to `3`. However my testing result shows that the second query won't go through until the first commits.

When the key is not unique this won't happen.

Is there a way to get around the table locking?

Comment: **You** know that these two updates are not interfering with each other, but mysql cannot possible know that in any given point of time there are no updates that would interfere with each other.

Comment: In my opinion this should be theoretically possible. Just check all the existing keys plus all the uncommited transactions, and then if the update value does not collide with any of those it should work. (MySQL already checks all the existing keys so part is done). Is there any reason MySQL did not support this approach or is it actually supported (by this or any other approach that reaches the same effect) just I don't know?

Comment: The check on existing keys places a shared lock on the keys.

Comment: Sorry I did not state clearly in the above comment. I meant "check on values of existing rows (which are already commited) and also check the "to-be-updated value" of rows that are being inserted/updated in transactions that are not commited". Shouldn't this approach work theoretically?

Comment: "MySQL already checks all the existing keys so part is done" By this line I meant if the process "checking the values on existing rows + checking the values on  uncommited transaction rows" is too slow, then "checking the values on existing rows" itself should be already slow. MySQL already did the ""checking the values on existing rows" part so why not do the "checking the values on  uncommited transaction rows" as well, which provides a better functionality?

Comment: How many records are there in your table? Only a few for testing purposes?

Comment: Currently yes there's only a few. However the intended record is going to be huge. Unfortunately I don't have the large scale testing environment set up yet.

Comment: In this case mysql may decide not to bother with the index to find the record to be updated, thus locking the entire table in the process. I do not think mysql would do the same for a larger record set.

Comment: Is there a documented threshold above which the MySQL behavior will be guaranteed to be optimized?

Comment: maybe this one is related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852861/unexpected-locking-for-table-with-primary-key-unique-key

Comment: Is there a good reason to have two unique keys?  That is, can you get rid of `id` and promote `foobar_id` to be the PK?

Comment: When testing things like this, be sure to have the values separated by some other value.  In some situations, "gap locking" is used.  You have ids 1 and 2, which are adjacent, and you have foo_ids 2 and 3 which are adjacent.  As one is being changed, the gap widens, possibly letting the other transaction fall into the same gap -- hence colliding.

Comment: I'm not aware of any documented tresholds.. please note, ignoring indexes for small populations is an opimisation technique.